# Didier Sornette's Strategy to Exploit Return Correlations

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, correlation-matrix

In his book, "Why Stock Markets Crash", Didier Sornette discusses a trading strategy that exploits return correlations.

> Consider a return $r$ that occurred at time $t$ and a return $r'$ that
>   occurred at a later time $t'$, where $t$ and $t'$, are multiples of
>   some time unit (say 5 minutes). $r$ and $r'$ can be decomposed into an
>   average contribution and a varying part. We are interested in
>   quantifying the correlation $C(t, t')$ between the uncertain varying
>   part, which is defined as the average of the product of the varying
>   part $r$ and of $r'$ normalized by the variance (volatility) of the
>   returns, so that $C(t, t' = t) = 1$ (perfect correlation between $r$
>   and itself).
>
> A simple mathematical calculation shows that the best linear predictor
>   $m_t$ for the return at time $t$, knowing the past history $r_{t-1},
> \> r_{t-2}, \ldots ,r_i, \ldots,$ is given by
>
> $$m_t\equiv\frac{1}{B(t, t)}\sum_{i<t} B(i, t)r_i,$$
>
> where each $B(i, t)$ is a factor that can be expressed in terms of the
>   correlation coefficient $C(t', t)$ and is usually called the
>   coefficient $(i, t)$ of the inverse correlation matrix. This formula
>   expresses that each past return $r_i$ impacts on the future return
>   $r_t$ in proportion to its value with a coefficient $B(i, t)/B(t, t)$
>   which is nonzero only if there is nonzero correlation between time $i$
>   and time $t$. With this formula, you have the best linear predictor in
>   the sense that it will minimize the errors in variance. Armed with
>   this prediction, you have a powerful trading strategy: buy if $m_t \>
> > 0$ (expected future price increase) and sell if $m_t < 0$ (expected
>   future price decrease).

I'm trying to solve for $m_t$ given the following dataset...

```
+----------+-----------------+
| t        | r               |
+----------+-----------------+
| 15:50:00 | 0.003705090715  |
| 15:51:00 | 0.003873999746  |
| 15:52:00 | 0.002158853672  |
| 15:53:00 | 0.001246754886  |
| 15:54:00 | 0.005646756563  |
| 15:55:00 | -0.001073638262 |
| 15:56:00 | -0.001804395665 |
| 15:57:00 | 0.002322446782  |
| 15:58:00 | 0.001803468933  |
| 15:59:00 | -0.001686730014 |
| 16:00:00 | 0.0008781111203 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

First I create a matrix for time lags $r_{t}, r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, r_{t-3}, r_{t-4}$, called $\color{blue}{\mathbf M}$...
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \color{blue}{0.00087811} & \color{blue}{-0.00168673} &  \color{blue}{0.00180347} &  \color{blue}{0.00232245} & -0.0018044  \\
-0.00168673 &  0.00180347 &  0.00232245 & -0.0018044  & -0.00107364 \\
 0.00180347 &  0.00232245 & -0.0018044  & -0.00107364 &  0.00564676 \\
 0.00232245 & -0.0018044  & -0.00107364 &  0.00564676 &  0.00124675 \\
-0.0018044  & -0.00107364 &  0.00564676 &  0.00124675 &  0.00215885 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
With $\color{blue}{\mathbf M}$ I am able to create a correlation matrix, called $\color{green}{\mathbf C}$...
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1.         &  \color{green}{-0.15885375} & -0.88120533 &  0.52518141 &  0.32904361 \\
-0.15885375 &  1.         & \color{green}{-0.27689212} & -0.87324435 &  0.43345156 \\
-0.88120533 & -0.27689212 &  1.         & \color{green}{-0.16496963} & -0.38678436 \\
 0.52518141 & -0.87324435 & -0.16496963 &  1.         & \color{green}{-0.18292072} \\
 0.32904361 &  0.43345156 & -0.38678436 & -0.18292072 &  1.         \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and its inverse, called $\color{red}{\mathbf I}$...
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \color{red}{678.1834365} &  -47.5405215 & 305.9166473 & -205.4095813 & -138.3472675 \\
 -47.5405215 &  557.4221492 &  89.6736779 &  245.3640449 & -138.7710611 \\
 305.9166473 &   89.6736779 & 111.2290498 &  -89.4926475 &   61.0341470 \\
-205.4095813 &  245.3640449 & -89.4926475 &  323.4950056 &   -2.4011426 \\
-138.3472675 & -138.7710611 &  61.0341470 &   -2.4011426 &  120.3071511 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Next I solve for...
$$
\sum_{i<t} \color{green}{B(i, t)}\color{blue}{r_i},
$$
as follows...
$$
\color{green}{\mathbf{C}[0][1]} \left( \color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][0]} \right) +
\color{green}{\mathbf{C}[1][2]} \left( \color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][1]} \right) +
\color{green}{\mathbf{C}[2][3]} \left( \color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][2]} \right) +
\color{green}{\mathbf{C}[3][4]} \left( \color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][3]} \right) = -0.000394790246734
$$
Finally I multiply by $\frac{1}{B(t,t)}$ which *I think* is equal to $\color{red}{\mathbf{I}[0][0]}$...
$$
\begin{align}
m_t & = -0.000394790246734\left( \frac{1}{B(t,t)} \right) \\
& = -0.000394790246734\left( \color{red}{\mathbf{I}[0][0]} \right) \\
& = -0.000394790246734\left( 678.1834365 \right) \\ 
& = -0.267740206251 \\
\end{align}
$$
Did I solve for $m_t$ correctly?

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=tAtpDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=why+stock+markets+crash&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ_7mmofTWAhUhxYMKHe2_CDgQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=why%20stock%20markets%20crash&f=false) is a link to the book. The strategy I reference above starts on page 36.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand why t is zero in B(t,t) and 1,2,3,4 in B(i,t).  And why did you interprete the value B(i,t) as the inverse of C, but not B(t,t)?
I think B(i,t) is the first column of I. An inverse is defined by Matrix^-1. But, B(*) is a value. So, you should divide by B(t,t). Here, you multiplicate it.

Comment: Does this look correct?
$$
\begin{align}
m_t &\equiv\frac{1}{B(t, t)}\sum_{i<t} B(i, t)r_i,\\
&\equiv\frac{1}{B(t, t)}
\biggl(
\color{red}{\mathbf I[1][0]}
\bigl(\color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][1]}\bigr)+
\color{red}{\mathbf I[2][0]}
\bigl(\color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][2]}\bigr)+
\color{red}{\mathbf I[3][0]}
\bigl(\color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][3]}\bigr)+
\color{red}{\mathbf I[4][0]}
\bigl(\color{blue}{\mathbf{M}[0][4]}\bigr)
\biggr)\\
&\equiv\frac{1}{678.1834365}\biggl(-415.4229687\biggr)\\
&\equiv\frac{-415.4229687}{678.1834365}\\
&\equiv\bbox[yellow]{-0.6125525136}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: [Here](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/didier-sornettes-strategy-to-exploit-return-correlations) is a backtest of the strategy just for fun. Note: transaction costs and slippage modeling are both turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't just do a least square regression ? 
It is likely not stable no ?